# IBM Unica Campaign External CSV File Import

Tags: ibm-cloud

I would like to import external csv file to maillist box.

Is there any way to import external csv file to Unica maillist box? Thank you.

Comment: please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hello, I will create a Unica flowchart to extract data. Later, i will manually change something in data. Can i import this manually changed csv file into Unica maillist box?

Answer (score 0):

In the edit mode of your flowchart, select the Admin drop down and choose Tables.
Map your .csv data as a base record table from your data source.
Make sure that the audience is the same as your MailList so that your data will show as an option.
then you should be able to run your Mail List process using your data.